# Is it possible to circumvent public key authentication restrictions using SSH daemon?

Tags: ssh, authentication, daemon, public-key

My web hosting plan does not support public key authentication, however advice given in [Public key authentication unsupported by web host. Method to avoid entering password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73487/public-key-authentication-unsupported-by-web-host-method-to-avoid-entering-pass/73503#73503) question suggests it may be possible to achieve using an SSH Daemon?

Is it possible to do and if so how?

Comment: it would be unwise to do something that circumvents your web hosts restrictions, as it may get your account terminated - i still wonder why they disable public key auth but allow password auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pure webhosting plan, chances are high that your provider will not allow you to run your own SSH daemon. But you have to check that with your provider first.